# Edit Text in expanded list

Tags: android, android-listview, android-edittext

I've been a little bit struggling with this one. So I have expandable list, and I want to make Edit Text for entering data. I created a button so I could use entered data on button activation(On Click). Also I created an Edit Text view. But when I want to receive that data, nothing happens, I use `edittex.getText().toString()`. I used Log.i to test but logger even does not appeared on logcat.

**ExpandableListAdapter**

```
package lt.whiteGroup.ultimateshoppinglist;

import java.util.logging.Logger;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.util.SparseArray;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.webkit.WebView.FindListener;
import android.widget.BaseExpandableListAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.CheckedTextView;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MyExpandableListAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter {

    private final SparseArray<Group> groups;
    public LayoutInflater inflater;
    public Activity activity;
    private Button but;
    private EditText edittex;


    public MyExpandableListAdapter(Activity act, SparseArray<Group> groups) {
        activity = act;
        this.groups = groups;
        inflater = act.getLayoutInflater();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getChild(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        return groups.get(groupPosition).children.get(childPosition);
    }

    @Override
    public long getChildId(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getChildView(int groupPosition, final int childPosition,
            boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        final String children = (String) getChild(groupPosition, childPosition);

        TextView text = null;
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.listrow_details, null);
        }
        text = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        text.setText(children);
//      convertView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
//          @Override
//          public void onClick(View v) {
//              Toast.makeText(activity, children,
//                      Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
//          }
//      });
        but = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.Button);
        edittex = (EditText) convertView.findViewById(R.id.ET);

        but.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                 EditText et = ((ViewGroup)v.getParent()).getChildAt(0);
                 System.out.println(et.getText().toString());
    //          Log.i("dsds", c);

            }
        });
        return convertView;
    }

    @Override
    public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition) {
        return groups.get(groupPosition).children.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getGroup(int groupPosition) {
        return groups.get(groupPosition);
    }

    @Override
    public int getGroupCount() {
        return groups.size();
    }

    @Override
    public void onGroupCollapsed(int groupPosition) {
        super.onGroupCollapsed(groupPosition);
    }

    @Override
    public void onGroupExpanded(int groupPosition) {
        super.onGroupExpanded(groupPosition);
    }

    @Override
    public long getGroupId(int groupPosition) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded,
            View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.listrow_group, null);
        }
        Group group = (Group) getGroup(groupPosition);
        ((CheckedTextView) convertView).setText(group.string);
        ((CheckedTextView) convertView).setChecked(isExpanded);
        return convertView;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasStableIds() {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isChildSelectable(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        return false;
    }

}
```

**LOG**

```
09-10 21:54:37.851: E/AndroidRuntime(1025): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-10 21:54:37.851: E/AndroidRuntime(1025): java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.TextView
09-10 21:54:37.851: E/AndroidRuntime(1025):     at lt.whiteGroup.ultimateshoppinglist.MyExpandableListAdapter$1.onClick(MyExpandableListAdapter.java:70)
09-10 21:54:37.851: E/AndroidRuntime(1025):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2485)
09-10 21:54:37.851: E/AndroidRuntime(1025):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:9080)
09-10 21:54:37.851: E/AndroidRuntime(1025):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
09-10 21:54:37.851: E/AndroidRuntime(1025):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
09-10 21:54:37.851: E/AndroidRuntime(1025):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
09-10 21:54:37.851: E/AndroidRuntime(1025):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3687)
09-10 21:54:37.851: E/AndroidRuntime(1025):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-10 21:54:37.851: E/AndroidRuntime(1025):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
09-10 21:54:37.851: E/AndroidRuntime(1025):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:867)
09-10 21:54:37.851: E/AndroidRuntime(1025):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:625)
09-10 21:54:37.851: E/AndroidRuntime(1025):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

**ListRowDetails Layout**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingLeft="40dp"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:drawablePadding="5dp"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:text="@string/hello_world"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" 

        >
    </TextView>

    <View
        android:layout_below="@id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:background="@android:color/black" />
    <Button 
       android:id="@+id/Button"
       android:layout_marginTop="1dp"
       android:layout_below="@id/textView1"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
       android:text="Add to list"
       android:onClick="ButtonFunction" 
        />
    <EditText 
       android:id="@+id/ET" 
       android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
       android:layout_toRightOf="@id/textView1"
       android:inputType="text"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
       android:hint="Quantity"
        />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: It seems that you've named your `Button` as 'Button". This will cause an error, rename it something else e.g. `b` and use `b.setOnClickListener(...` and see if that helps

Comment: @EdGeorge The name of the button variable has nothing to do with it. It's the variable that he's calling inside of the click event.

Comment: Button name changed, still the same :/. Any other thoughts? I think it should have something with list I think, maybe I need to determine which list item's editText is being edited?

Comment: @whiteLT I've added an answer.

Comment: Ok, refreshing, one sec :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't grab the value of an arbitrarily created/added view like that. In your onClick event, `edittex` is referring to the class scope `EditText edittex` variable (which is never initialized / used BTW). Since the onClick listener will be called at an undetermined time, this is not the way you should reference your EditText field. Assuming you have the following layout:

```
<LinearLayout>
    <EditText />
    <Button />
</LinearLayout>
```

You should do something that doesn't rely on variables that have been initialized outside of the onClickListener, like this:

```
    // Make sure to that you are referencing the button variable and not the Button class here
    yourButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            EditText et = (EditText) ((ViewGroup)v.getParent()).getChildAt(0);
            System.out.println(et.getText().toString());
            // You can use the logger if you want, but I always find it easier to use System.out if I'm just printing out one value.
        }
    });
```

**Explination:**

In general, when using an ExpandableListView, ListView, or any other view that allows for an arbitrary number of views to be added to it, I find it easiest go to the parent of the clicked view to find any sibling views. You can't reference a local variable that has been declared inside of a different method. So, this line: `String c = edittex.getText().toString();` is actually referring to the `EditText edittex` variable that has a class scope (the one you declared at the top of the class). That variable is either: a) never initialized, or b) the value is overwritten by a subsequent method call. As such, when you reference it, you're not referencing the variable that you think you are.

To overcome this, all you need to do is use the `View` that is passed as a parameter to get the parent that contains it (which is a subclass of ViewGroup if you had a similar layout to the one I showed you an example of). Once you do that, you can access any of the parent's child views via the `getChildAt()` method. In this case, I'm assuming that the `EditText` view is the first child view of the parent (the one at the 0th index). Adjust the index as necessary.

Also, this line: `Button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {` should be the name of your `Button` variable, not the `Button` class.

Comment: Ok, thanks, checking your code now, in the mean while could you please explane this line:
EditText et = ((ViewGroup)v.getParent()).getChildAt(0);
why we use ViewGroup and child at 0?

Comment: @whiteLT I just put one up there. Make sense?

Comment: Yes, thank you very much for your explanation, really helped! But now eclipse wants me to add casting to your line of code. I updated my code above. If I add casting I get force close

Comment: Sorry. Yes, you'll need to cast it to an EditText. Does it force close when you do that? If so, what error does it give you?

Comment: Ok. I saw it. Your problem is that you need to change the index of the `getChildAt()`. The view at your 0th index is a TextView, not an EditText. Do you understand what I mean?

Comment: Yes, if I understand right `((ViewGroup)v.getParent()).getChildAt(1);` `((ViewGroup)v.getParent())` automatically chooses selected parent and I need to choose `getChildAt(x)` but how to know that?

Comment: Look at your view layout that you use for each item in your ExpandableListView. From there you can see what each child view's index is. There are other ways to do this, but this is the easiest. If you prefer, you can post the layout that you use for each item in your ExpandalbeListView and I'll show you what I mean.

Comment: Do you mean that I need to count from top? And in this case my int is 4?

Comment: Yes, that's correct. Except, don't forget that the index is 0-based. Which means that 4 is really index 3. E.g. getChildAt(3) will give you your EditText.

Comment: Works!!! Great! But I still have two mysteries to solve :D. 1. First why when I rotate screen edit text goes empty. 2. Second how android knows which one button I pressed? :)

Comment: I can make separate questions if you have time for this stuff :) By the way I would like to say you are very good teacher :)

Comment: Thanks! Haha I do have time. Let's go ahead and move this to a chat and I'll answer those questions for you.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/37128/discussion-between-don-and-whitelt)